# Cannot resize SVG dynamically with JS (only works on desktop)

Tags: javascript, css, svg

### Trying to create a modal that allows users to rate businesses (1 - 5 stars).

#### What I came up with works great on desktop browsers (tested on Chrome and Safari) but doesn't work in mobile browsers.

My solution uses SVG and JS. When a user clicks star 5, for example, the SVG rectangle (#modal-fill-orange) within #modal-rating expands in width to fill the stars.

```js
let content = document.createElement('div');
let ratingChosen = null;

content.innerHTML = UserLib.ratingStarsModalClipSVG;
content.style.fill = 'white';

content.style.height = '160px';
content.style.width = '180px';

let customModal = document.getElementById('custom-modal');
customModal.appendChild(content);

let orangeFill = content.querySelector('#modal-fill-orange');
let stars = content.querySelectorAll('.modal-star');
let unfilledStars = content.querySelector('#modal-unfilled-stars');
unfilledStars.style.fill = 'gray';

// need to create abs positioned overlay to receive click input

let absOverlay = document.createElement('ul');
absOverlay.id = 'modal-abs-overlay';

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let li = document.createElement('li');
  li.id = ('li-' + i);
  absOverlay.appendChild(li);
}

customModal.appendChild(absOverlay);

for (let j = 0; j < absOverlay.children.length; j++) {
  document.getElementById(`li-${j}`).addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#modal-fill-orange').style.width = (20 + (j * 20)) + '%';
    ratingChosen = j + 1;
  });
}
```

```html
var UserLib = {

ratingStarsModalClipSVG:  `<svg id='modal-rating' xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 315 60">
    <clipPath id='modal-clip'>
      <path d="M583.7,276c.29-1.83.55-3.52.82-5.22.78-4.88,1.56-9.76,2.31-14.64a1.09,1.09,0,0,0-.33-.71q-6.81-6.7-13.63-13.4a4.71,4.71,0,0,0-.57-.38l.13-.19,5.23-.83c4.83-.77,9.66-1.53,14.48-2.32a1,1,0,0,0,.56-.52q3-5.91,5.87-11.82l2.65-5.35c.09-.18.2-.36.33-.62.14.25.25.44.35.64q4.32,8.49,8.62,17a1,1,0,0,0,.88.67c4.25.61,8.49,1.25,12.74,1.88l6.4.94a2.07,2.07,0,0,1,.33.1l.18.2a2.92,2.92,0,0,0-.6.34l-13.51,13.53a.89.89,0,0,0-.29.89q1.62,9.48,3.2,19c0,.2,0,.4.09.69l-2-1q-7.77-4-15.54-8a1.24,1.24,0,0,0-1.31,0c-5.57,2.95-11.16,5.86-16.74,8.79Z" transform="translate(-570.3 -218)"/>
      <path d="M646.7,276c.29-1.83.55-3.52.82-5.22.78-4.88,1.56-9.76,2.31-14.64a1.09,1.09,0,0,0-.33-.71q-6.81-6.7-13.63-13.4a4.71,4.71,0,0,0-.57-.38l.13-.19,5.23-.83c4.83-.77,9.66-1.53,14.48-2.32a1,1,0,0,0,.56-.52q3-5.91,5.87-11.82l2.65-5.35c.09-.18.2-.36.33-.62.14.25.25.44.35.64q4.32,8.49,8.62,17a1,1,0,0,0,.88.67c4.25.61,8.49,1.25,12.74,1.88l6.4.94a2.07,2.07,0,0,1,.33.1l.18.2a2.92,2.92,0,0,0-.6.34l-13.51,13.53a.89.89,0,0,0-.29.89q1.62,9.48,3.2,19c0,.2,0,.4.09.69l-2-1q-7.77-4-15.54-8a1.24,1.24,0,0,0-1.31,0c-5.57,2.95-11.16,5.86-16.74,8.79Z" transform="translate(-570.3 -218)"/>
      <path d="M709.7,276c.29-1.83.55-3.52.82-5.22.78-4.88,1.56-9.76,2.31-14.64a1.09,1.09,0,0,0-.33-.71q-6.81-6.7-13.63-13.4a4.71,4.71,0,0,0-.57-.38l.13-.19,5.23-.83c4.83-.77,9.66-1.53,14.48-2.32a1,1,0,0,0,.56-.52q3-5.91,5.87-11.82l2.65-5.35c.09-.18.2-.36.33-.62.14.25.25.44.35.64q4.32,8.49,8.62,17a1,1,0,0,0,.88.67c4.25.61,8.49,1.25,12.74,1.88l6.4.94a2.07,2.07,0,0,1,.33.1l.18.2a2.92,2.92,0,0,0-.6.34l-13.51,13.53a.89.89,0,0,0-.29.89q1.62,9.48,3.2,19c0,.2,0,.4.09.69l-2-1q-7.77-4-15.54-8a1.24,1.24,0,0,0-1.31,0c-5.57,2.95-11.16,5.86-16.74,8.79Z" transform="translate(-570.3 -218)"/>
      <path d="M772.7,276c.29-1.83.55-3.52.82-5.22.78-4.88,1.56-9.76,2.31-14.64a1.09,1.09,0,0,0-.33-.71q-6.81-6.7-13.63-13.4a4.71,4.71,0,0,0-.57-.38l.13-.19,5.23-.83c4.83-.77,9.66-1.53,14.48-2.32a1,1,0,0,0,.56-.52q3-5.91,5.87-11.82l2.65-5.35c.09-.18.2-.36.33-.62.14.25.25.44.35.64q4.32,8.49,8.62,17a1,1,0,0,0,.88.67c4.25.61,8.49,1.25,12.74,1.88l6.4.94a2.07,2.07,0,0,1,.33.1l.18.2a2.92,2.92,0,0,0-.6.34l-13.51,13.53a.89.89,0,0,0-.29.89q1.62,9.48,3.2,19c0,.2,0,.4.09.69l-2-1q-7.77-4-15.54-8a1.24,1.24,0,0,0-1.31,0c-5.57,2.95-11.16,5.86-16.74,8.79Z" transform="translate(-570.3 -218)"/>
      <path d="M835.7,276c.29-1.83.55-3.52.82-5.22.78-4.88,1.56-9.76,2.31-14.64a1.09,1.09,0,0,0-.33-.71q-6.81-6.7-13.63-13.4a4.71,4.71,0,0,0-.57-.38l.13-.19,5.23-.83c4.83-.77,9.66-1.53,14.48-2.32a1,1,0,0,0,.56-.52q3-5.91,5.87-11.82l2.65-5.35c.09-.18.2-.36.33-.62.14.25.25.44.35.64q4.32,8.49,8.62,17a1,1,0,0,0,.88.67c4.25.61,8.49,1.25,12.74,1.88l6.4.94a2.07,2.07,0,0,1,.33.1l.18.2a2.92,2.92,0,0,0-.6.34l-13.51,13.53a.89.89,0,0,0-.29.89q1.62,9.48,3.2,19c0,.2,0,.4.09.69l-2-1q-7.77-4-15.54-8a1.24,1.24,0,0,0-1.31,0c-5.57,2.95-11.16,5.86-16.74,8.79Z" transform="translate(-570.3 -218)"/>
    </clipPath>
    <rect id='modal-fill-orange' height="60"/>
    <g id='modal-unfilled-stars'>
      <path class='modal-star' d="M583.7,276c.29-1.83.55-3.52.82-5.22.78-4.88,1.56-9.76,2.31-14.64a1.09,1.09,0,0,0-.33-.71q-6.81-6.7-13.63-13.4a4.71,4.71,0,0,0-.57-.38l.13-.19,5.23-.83c4.83-.77,9.66-1.53,14.48-2.32a1,1,0,0,0,.56-.52q3-5.91,5.87-11.82l2.65-5.35c.09-.18.2-.36.33-.62.14.25.25.44.35.64q4.32,8.49,8.62,17a1,1,0,0,0,.88.67c4.25.61,8.49,1.25,12.74,1.88l6.4.94a2.07,2.07,0,0,1,.33.1l.18.2a2.92,2.92,0,0,0-.6.34l-13.51,13.53a.89.89,0,0,0-.29.89q1.62,9.48,3.2,19c0,.2,0,.4.09.69l-2-1q-7.77-4-15.54-8a1.24,1.24,0,0,0-1.31,0c-5.57,2.95-11.16,5.86-16.74,8.79Z" transform="translate(-570.3 -218)"/>
      <path class='modal-star' d="M646.7,276c.29-1.83.55-3.52.82-5.22.78-4.88,1.56-9.76,2.31-14.64a1.09,1.09,0,0,0-.33-.71q-6.81-6.7-13.63-13.4a4.71,4.71,0,0,0-.57-.38l.13-.19,5.23-.83c4.83-.77,9.66-1.53,14.48-2.32a1,1,0,0,0,.56-.52q3-5.91,5.87-11.82l2.65-5.35c.09-.18.2-.36.33-.62.14.25.25.44.35.64q4.32,8.49,8.62,17a1,1,0,0,0,.88.67c4.25.61,8.49,1.25,12.74,1.88l6.4.94a2.07,2.07,0,0,1,.33.1l.18.2a2.92,2.92,0,0,0-.6.34l-13.51,13.53a.89.89,0,0,0-.29.89q1.62,9.48,3.2,19c0,.2,0,.4.09.69l-2-1q-7.77-4-15.54-8a1.24,1.24,0,0,0-1.31,0c-5.57,2.95-11.16,5.86-16.74,8.79Z" transform="translate(-570.3 -218)"/>
      <path class='modal-star' d="M709.7,276c.29-1.83.55-3.52.82-5.22.78-4.88,1.56-9.76,2.31-14.64a1.09,1.09,0,0,0-.33-.71q-6.81-6.7-13.63-13.4a4.71,4.71,0,0,0-.57-.38l.13-.19,5.23-.83c4.83-.77,9.66-1.53,14.48-2.32a1,1,0,0,0,.56-.52q3-5.91,5.87-11.82l2.65-5.35c.09-.18.2-.36.33-.62.14.25.25.44.35.64q4.32,8.49,8.62,17a1,1,0,0,0,.88.67c4.25.61,8.49,1.25,12.74,1.88l6.4.94a2.07,2.07,0,0,1,.33.1l.18.2a2.92,2.92,0,0,0-.6.34l-13.51,13.53a.89.89,0,0,0-.29.89q1.62,9.48,3.2,19c0,.2,0,.4.09.69l-2-1q-7.77-4-15.54-8a1.24,1.24,0,0,0-1.31,0c-5.57,2.95-11.16,5.86-16.74,8.79Z" transform="translate(-570.3 -218)"/>
      <path class='modal-star' d="M772.7,276c.29-1.83.55-3.52.82-5.22.78-4.88,1.56-9.76,2.31-14.64a1.09,1.09,0,0,0-.33-.71q-6.81-6.7-13.63-13.4a4.71,4.71,0,0,0-.57-.38l.13-.19,5.23-.83c4.83-.77,9.66-1.53,14.48-2.32a1,1,0,0,0,.56-.52q3-5.91,5.87-11.82l2.65-5.35c.09-.18.2-.36.33-.62.14.25.25.44.35.64q4.32,8.49,8.62,17a1,1,0,0,0,.88.67c4.25.61,8.49,1.25,12.74,1.88l6.4.94a2.07,2.07,0,0,1,.33.1l.18.2a2.92,2.92,0,0,0-.6.34l-13.51,13.53a.89.89,0,0,0-.29.89q1.62,9.48,3.2,19c0,.2,0,.4.09.69l-2-1q-7.77-4-15.54-8a1.24,1.24,0,0,0-1.31,0c-5.57,2.95-11.16,5.86-16.74,8.79Z" transform="translate(-570.3 -218)"/>
      <path class='modal-star' d="M835.7,276c.29-1.83.55-3.52.82-5.22.78-4.88,1.56-9.76,2.31-14.64a1.09,1.09,0,0,0-.33-.71q-6.81-6.7-13.63-13.4a4.71,4.71,0,0,0-.57-.38l.13-.19,5.23-.83c4.83-.77,9.66-1.53,14.48-2.32a1,1,0,0,0,.56-.52q3-5.91,5.87-11.82l2.65-5.35c.09-.18.2-.36.33-.62.14.25.25.44.35.64q4.32,8.49,8.62,17a1,1,0,0,0,.88.67c4.25.61,8.49,1.25,12.74,1.88l6.4.94a2.07,2.07,0,0,1,.33.1l.18.2a2.92,2.92,0,0,0-.6.34l-13.51,13.53a.89.89,0,0,0-.29.89q1.62,9.48,3.2,19c0,.2,0,.4.09.69l-2-1q-7.77-4-15.54-8a1.24,1.24,0,0,0-1.31,0c-5.57,2.95-11.16,5.86-16.74,8.79Z" transform="translate(-570.3 -218)"/>
    </g>
    <use clip-path="url(#modal-clip)" xlink:href="#modal-fill-orange" fill="rgb(255, 154, 0)" />
  </svg>`

}
```

Any ideas why this would work perfectly on desktop browsers, but not on mobile? To be specific, the rating system DOES work on mobile, but #modal-fill-orange does not expand when clicking.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include your whole code? Seems `customModal` definition is missing

Comment: Included full code from my custom library. I hope it helps, though it does grab data from other libraries.

Comment: Why are you setting `style` attributes directly, instead of using normal classes? Also, given that your SVG has a def that gets used exactly once: why is that split up? (run that SVG through `svgo` or something, it's a bit weird atm) And finally, _don't use innerHTML_: if you need to set text, do that (using `.textContent = ...`) and if you need DOM content, do that using normal DOM functions (createElement, appendChild, etc).

Comment: Agreed that style attributes could be moved. But this SVG gets used multiple times throughout the app.

Answer (score 0):

This one had me stumped for a while. It looks like on some browsers, editing the clipping path via js doesn't trigger a redraw of the SVG.

I opted to ditch the  and  tags and break my SVG into 2 separate files, unfilled stars and filled stars. I then used CSS clip-path property to properly fill the clicked stars, which doesn't work with Safari without -webkit- prefix.

```
let ratingChosen = null;
content.innerHTML = UserLib.ratingStarsFilledSVG + UserLib.ratingStarsUnfilledSVG;

// need to create abs positioned overlay to receive click input
    let absOverlay = document.createElement('ul');
    absOverlay.id = 'modal-abs-overlay';

    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      let li = document.createElement('li');
      li.id = ('li-' + i);
      absOverlay.appendChild(li);
    }

    customModal.appendChild(absOverlay);

    for (let j = 0; j < absOverlay.children.length; j++) {
      document.getElementById(`li-${j}`).addEventListener('click', () => {

        starIdx = j + 1; // 1 - 5
        document.getElementById('rating-stars-filled').style.clipPath = `inset(0px ${(100 - (starIdx * 20)) + '%'} 0px 0px)`;
        document.getElementById('rating-stars-filled').style.webkitClipPath = `inset(0px ${(100 - (starIdx * 20)) + '%'} 0px 0px)`;
        ratingChosen = starIdx;
      });
    }
```